# (GNU make) installcheck a library

Tags: makefile, installation, shared-libraries

How do I implement the make `installcheck` target when building a library? That is, I have a `check` target that creates a test program that links to the created library, called by some script in order to check if the library code functions properly, and I wish to perform the same checks but linking to the library *after* it has been installed; how can I implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I can't find any guides on this, I will present the method that I have come up with, which has been patched together from reading the [GNU automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/) and some general trial and error. It might be ugly, but it works...

If the check routines for building a library involve linking the library to a test program and seeing if that program works correctly, then to installcheck the library we need only do the same thing but link the test program to the installed library rather than the locally built library.

Let's call the library **alpha** (so we'll be creating *libalpha.so* and/or *libalpha.a*). Supposing alpha's source code is in the file *alpha.cpp* in the *src* directory, we'll create *src/Makefile.am* as usual:

```
# src/Makefile.am

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libalpha.la
libalpha_la_SOURCES = alpha.cpp
include_HEADERS = alpha.h
```

The check routine involves creating a binary **beta** that links to *alpha*. The source code for *beta* is in the file *beta.cpp* in the directory *tests*. The automake file *tests/Makefile.am* looks like this:

```
# tests/Makefile.am

check_PROGRAMS = beta
beta_SOURCES = beta.cpp
beta_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/src
beta_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libalpha.la
```

We will create our `check` and `installcheck` routines by creating "local" targets in *tests/Makefile.am* like so:

```
# tests/Makefile.am

# ...

check-local:
    # recipe to run when 'make check' is called.

installcheck-local:
    # recipe to run when 'make installcheck' is called.
```

The `check` and `installcheck` targets conflict because use of either target prevents the other target from executing properly (one target "taints" the build tree for the other target); in order for the other target to execute properly we need to remove *beta* and its object files and have the target recompile and re-link as it sees fit according to its nature (`installcheck` to installed files, `check` to local files).

We can solve this issue of tainted build trees by simply running `make clean` in the recipe of both targets. This will clearly remove the tainted builds, but is overzealous because we don't need to rebuild whenever we run the same target again. The build tree is only tainted whenever we run the other target.

We can only solve this complication by remembering which of the two targets had been called previously, which we can do via the creation/destruction of an intermediary file (let's call it **taint**). The `check` target is tainted whenever the file *taint* exists, which it resolves by cleaning, rebuilding and removing *taint*; and the `installcheck` target is tainted when the file *taint* does not exist, which it resolves by cleaning, rebuilding and creating *taint*.

Our targets will take the form:

```
# tests/Makefile.am

# ...

check-local:
      # First, check to see if the build tree is tainted and rebuild if so
    test ! -f taint || $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) check_rebuild
      # Then, run our check tests. Substitute with your shell scripts or testsuite files as appropriate
    ./beta

installcheck-local:
      # First, check to see if the build tree is tainted and rebuild if so
    test -f taint || $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) installcheck_rebuild
      # Then, run our installcheck tests. Substitute with your shell scripts or testsuite files as appropriate
    ./beta
```

The target `check_rebuild` needs to rebuild according to how `check` will run, and will look like this:

```
# tests/Makefile.am

# ...

.PHONY: check_rebuild
check_rebuild:
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) clean          # remove tainted build tree
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) beta$(EXEEXT)  # rebuild beta
    rm -f taint                            # mark build tree as untainted
```

The target `installcheck_rebuild` likewise looks like this:

```
# tests/Makefile.am

# ...

.PHONY: installcheck_rebuild
installcheck_rebuild:
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) clean          # remove tainted build tree
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) beta$(EXEEXT) \
      beta_CPPFLAGS="-I$(DESTDIR)$(includedir)" \
      beta_LDADD="$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/libalpha.la" \
      beta_DEPENDENCIES="$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/libalpha.la"
    echo 1 > taint                         # mark build tree as untainted
```

Note that rebuilding *beta* in `installcheck_rebuild` now requires the overriding of the automake variables so that they point to the installed library.

Finally, we need to add the taint file to `DISTCLEANFILES` so that running `distcheck` does not fail with "files left in build directory after distclean" errors.

And that should be it. The final *tests/Makefile.am* should look like this:

```
# tests/Makefile.am

check_PROGRAMS = beta
beta_SOURCES = beta.cpp
beta_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/src
beta_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libalpha.la

taint_file = .taint

check-local:
    test ! -f $(taint_file) || $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) check_rebuild
    ./beta # substitute with your actual test routines

installcheck-local:
    test -f $(taint_file) || $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) installcheck_rebuild
    ./beta # substitute with your actual test routines

.PHONY: check_rebuild
check_rebuild:
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) clean
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) beta$(EXEEXT)
    rm -f $(taint_file)

.PHONY: installcheck_rebuild
installcheck_rebuild:
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) clean
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) beta$(EXEEXT) \
      beta_CPPFLAGS="-I$(DESTDIR)$(includedir)" \
      beta_LDADD="$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/libalpha.la" \
      beta_DEPENDENCIES="$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/libalpha.la"
    echo 1 > $(taint_file)

DISTCLEANFILES = $(taint_file)
```

### Disclaimer

This has been checked on Linux for a "standard" build, but it may not work on other build environments or if you are trying to do something "exotic". Hopefully it should, but it is not something that I have bothered to check. If there are errors, the problem will likely be a missing or misused variable in one of my targets above.

For example, the `check_rebuild` target has the line:

```
check_rebuild:
    # ...
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) beta$(EXEEXT)
    # ...
```

The variables `$(AM_MAKEFLAGS)` and `$(EXEEXT)` are a part of how automake itself creates routines to populate in the Makefiles it creates, and had I neglected them in my targets above, then it might have caused the build to fail (or at least not function as expected).

I have tried to make sure the targets that I have suggested above are likewise canonically constructed, but I may have missed something out. Your best bet in case of build errors is to open the Makefiles generated by automake itself during the build, seeing how it is creating objects and mimicking those constructs in the corresponding Makefile.am files, as I have tried to do.

The other likely issue may be in the "hackish" way I've built the *beta* binary in the `installcheck_rebuild` target. Again, your best bet in diagnosing problems will be to see how automake is doing things in the Makefiles it generates, and trying to mimic that. Otherwise, a read of the automake manual will be in order, and failing that, you will likely need the help of people more knowledgeable than me. Good luck.